# Word for separating into silos?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

In a business context, a silo is a department or task force that works on a specific project or area of the business independently (often with minimal if any contact) from other silos. I have a list of tasks, which need to be split up so they can be distributed among the various silos in the business.

> I am going to `word` the tasks.
>
> I am `word`ing the tasks.
>
> The tasks have been `word`ed.

What is `word`?

Comment: Do you mean that the list needs to be split up into a number of tasks, or that individual tasks need to be further subdivided?

Comment: @Spagirl that the list needs to be separated into several smaller lists, not that the tasks need to be themselves subdivided.

Comment: You could just use divided?

Comment: When in doubt (in business English), verb the noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **apportion**.

[Definition by Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apportion)

> to divide and share out (something) according to a plan

You can also use **allocate**

[definition by Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allocate)

> to divide and give out something for a special reason or to particular persons, things, companies, etc.

Other options are:

I am going to **delegate** the tasks.

I am **commissioning** the tasks.

I have **assigned** the tasks.

Please look up all these words for their synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to come rushing in as Captain Obvious, but [silo is also a verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/silo):

> Isolate (one system, process, department, etc.) from others

So, if you really want to end up with "silos" then go ahead:

> 1. I am going to silo the tasks.
> 2. I am siloing the tasks.
> 3. The tasks have been siloed.

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate, because it implies the *creation* of silos - I am looking for a word to describe the distribution of tasks among pre-existing silos.

Comment: No problem.  Although the dictionary definition states the isolation of tasks.  Whether the silo already exists or not is not implied.  My other alternative (already answered) would be to agree with "allocate".

Answer (score 1):

You can *partition* the tasks.

> **Partition** *verb*
>   Divide into parts
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/partition)

In your sample usage, you can use the word as follows:

- I am going to *partition* the tasks.
- I am *partitioning* the tasks.
- The tasks have been *partitioned*.

Here is an example of the word in context, with the idea of splitting up work that would be done independently:

> The    principle    of    partitioning    tasks    among    product 
>   development  teams  so  as  to  minimize  the  cost  of  interactions 
>   across  design  teams  is  an  important  characteristic  of  complex 
>   engineered  systems.
>   [- Dan Braha, PARTITIONING TASKS TO PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT TEAMS](http://www.necsi.edu/affiliates/braha/ASME-DETC2002-DTM34031.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Compartmentalize** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compartmentalize)

> *verb* to separate into isolated compartments or categories
>   *"The company has compartmentalized its services."*

See synonyms on [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/compartmentalize)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "silo" as a verb.

I am going to silo the tasks.

I am siloing the tasks.

I have siloed the tasks.

Even though spellcheck is choking on siloed: "Siloed is defined as to have put something into a silo." (http://www.yourdictionary.com/siloed)